# Combinatorics problem on $20$ people, $12$ months, and distinguishable groups

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Given $20$ people, what is the probability that, among the $12$ months
>   in the year, there are $4$ months containing exactly $2$ birthdays and
>   $4$ months containing exactly $3$ birthdays?

I am less concerned about knowing the answer than making sure I have thought about the problem correctly.

The general problem seems to be finding the distinct integer-valued vectors that satisfy
$$x_1 + x_2 + ... x_{12} = 20\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_i \ge 0, i = 1, ..., 12$$

It can be proven that there are $\binom{20+12-1}{12-1}$ such vectors. I am presuming this to be the sample space.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

$4\cdot 2 + 4\cdot 3 + 4 \cdot 0= 20$, so there are $3$ distinct groups of $4$ months. Therefore we have $\binom{12}{4\ 4\ 4}$ possible ways to get the desired distribution of months.

The probability I get is $$\frac{\binom{12}{4\ 4\ 4}}{\binom{20+12-1}{12-1}} $$. The answer in the back of the textbook is $1.0604 \times 10^{-3}$ so my answer is off. I just want to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Your proposed sample space is in principle fine. The problem is that the elements of the sample space cannot be assumed to be equally likely. If you want a sample space where all outcomes are equally likely (so that the probability can be computed by counting) then another sample space needs to be chosen.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, although the elements of the $\binom{20+12-1}{12-1}$ sample space are not equally likely, is there still a way to solve this problem using this as a sample space?

Comment: Yes, there is, but I would not want to do it that way, substantially more work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your count of the sample space treats the $20$ people as indistinguishable, when in fact they are not. The actual size of the sample space is $12^{20}$: each of the $20$ people can have a birthday in any of $12$ months. (We are making the simplifying assumption that the probability of being born in any given month is $\frac1{12}$; this is in fact false.)

To get the correct numerator, observe (as in effect you did) that there are $\binom{12}4$ ways to choose the $4$ months containing exactly $2$ birthdays and then $\binom84$ ways to choose the $4$ months containing exactly $3$ birthdays, so there are $\binom{12}4\binom84=\binom{12}{4\;4\;4}$ ways to choose the months. Then, however, the $20$ people have to be assigned to these months, and there are $$\binom{20}{3\;3\;3\;3\;2\;2\;2\;2}=\frac{20!}{12^4}$$ ways to do that. The desired probability is therefore

$$\frac{\binom{12}8\binom8420!}{12^{24}}\approx0.00106042\;.$$

Comment: When I first read the problem, I didn't see that the $20$ people are distinguishable. What labels the people, or are we imposing an ordering (labeling) over the people?
Also, if the each person is distinguishable, then why not also add the case $\binom{20}{3\ 3\ 3\ 2\ 3\ 2\ 2\ 2}$

Comment: @Trevor: People simply *are* distinguishable: Lisa having a May birthday and Amy a June birthday is different from Lisa having a June birthday and Amy a May birthday. Occasionally one encounters a problem in which people are to be treated as indistinguishable counters, but that’s always clearly indicated. // That’s not a distinct case; it’s simply listing the $8$ chosen months in a different order. Say we’ve chosen Jan, Feb, Mar, and Apr as the $3$-birthday months and May, Jun, Jul, and Aug as the $2$-birthday months; we can assign people to them in that order, or in the order Jan, Feb, ...

Comment: ... Mar, May, Apr, Jun, Jul, Aug (among many others); my multinomial coefficient corresponds to the calendar order (among others), yours to this new order (among others). But no matter in what order we fill the months, we’re performing the same task and have the same possible outcomes.

Comment: So then we would not reach the same result if we replaced "people" with "balls"?

Comment: @Trevor: That’s right, if the balls are understood to be indistinguishable (as is often the case).

Answer (score 0):

I was comparing answer by Brian M Scott to this question to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425764/336409) of another similar question (lets call it 2nd question and this problem as $1$ st problem). I had following doubt:

$2$ nd problem, case $i=2$ solution has $\binom{4}{1,3}+\binom{4}{2,2}+\binom{4}{3,1}$ in the numerator.
$2$ nd problem, case $i=3$ solution has $\binom{4}{1,1,2}+\binom{4}{1,2,1}+\binom{4}{2,1,1}$ in the numerator. Then why Brian's solution dont have sum of different multinomial coefficients in its numerator? For examles, why there is no $\binom{20}{3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2}+\binom{20}{3,3,3,2,3,2,2,2}+\binom{20}{3,3,2,2,3,3,2,2}+...$ in the numerator of Brian's solution for problem 1?

I gave it a thought for a while. I felt that in 2nd problem we are selecting repairmen which can be permuted. That is different repairman can be assigned different number of TV sets. Thus this is imitated combinatorically by having sum of different multinomial coefficients. In 1st problem we dont select individual months. But select two groups each of 4 months, each month in one group getting 2 birthdays and in other getting 3. Selecting different months in different groups serves as a permuting 2 or 3 birthdays to these different months. Hence we dont have to consider different multinomial coefficients as all months in one group get same number of birthdays.

So I started thinking whether I can convert answer of 1st question to have sum of multinomial coefficients in the numerator. I felt, for this I need to select individual months. We can select $8$ out of $12$ months in $\binom{12}{8}$ ways. We can distributed 20 birthdays in four groups of 3 and four groups of 2 in  $\binom{20}{3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2}\times \binom{8}{4}$ ways, where $\binom{8}{4}$ counts different sequences of $\{3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2\}$ we can have in first multinomial's $2$nd parameter. So the final solution is $$\frac{\binom{12}{8}\times \binom{20}{3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2}\times \binom{8}{4}}{12^{20}}$$ which turns out to be same as Brian's answer, that is approximately $0.00106042$