# Probability homework problem.

Tags: probability

The question is - A town contains $4$ people who repair televisions. If $4$ sets breakdown, what is the probability that exactly $1$ repairer is called?

My attempt - Consider the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=4$ where $x_i$ is the number of television sets that are brought to repairer $i$ to repair where $i=\{1,2,3,4\}$. The sum has to be equal to $4$ because there are $4$ television sets to be repaired. So, the sample space is all the integral solutions of the above equation which is $\binom{4+4-1}4=\binom74$. The event that we are interested in has four elements namely $\{4+0+0+0,0+4+0+0, 0+0+4+0, 0+0+0+4\}$. Therefore, the required answer is $\frac{4}{\binom74}= 0.11429$, which unfortunately doesn't match the given answer in the book. So, where am I going wrong?

I have already seen the answers given in [How to count permutations with restrictions on how items are grouped](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377270/how-to-count-permutations-with-restrictions-on-how-items-are-grouped) , and totally understood it, but I am not able to find where am I going wrong with my solution. Can anyone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are we to imagine that each owner of a broken TV calls a repair person from the list uniformly at random, independent of all the others?  If, so then the probability that they call call $A$ is $\frac 1{4^4}$.  Same for $B,C$ and $D$.  So...

Comment: The problem with your method is that the various configurations counted by Stars and Bars are not equally probable.

Comment: @lulu Yes, each owner of a broken TV calls a repair person from the list uniformly at random, independent of all the others.

Comment: @lulu But why is it not equally probable, can you explain?

Comment: There's only one way that everyone calls on A, but $24$ ways that each calls a different repairman.

Comment: It is far more likely that the choices be roughly even amongst the options than that they cluster in some specified way.  Try it with two objects and two slots.  The probability that exactly one object goes into each of the slots is $\frac 12$, while the probability that they all go into the first slot is $\frac 14$.

Comment: @lulu I am sorry, it's totally going over my head.

Comment: As a comment, the mistake you made is an *incredibly common* one.  It is something of a rite of passage.  Just remember that using counting techniques to find probabilities it must be the case that the outcomes in the sample space are equally likely.  Sometimes this means that you need to look at the sample space a different way, such as pretending that objects are uniquely labeled or having things happen in sequence or keeping track of which person called which tv repairman, rather than grouping these outcomes in a way that makes things no longer equiprobable.

Comment: Just work a small example by hand.  Try $3$ objects in $3$ slots.   There are $\binom 53=10$ possible patterns.  But the pattern $(3,0,0)$ say has probability $\frac 1{3^3}\neq \frac 1{10}$.

Comment: For the objects in slots example... compare the problem where the 3 objects appear at first glance to be identical to the problem where we noticed that the objects had unique serial numbers.  Suddenly noticing the serial numbers and gaining more insight doesn't change the probability, though it does allow us to be more careful with how we organize our thoughts and how we recognize each of the outcomes.  Looking at an outcome, we can now say where "*the first*" object went, where "*the second*" object went, etc...

Comment: Now... our assumptions about that each individual object was placed into the slots *uniformly* at random and *independently* at random from the others... that is exactly the language that implies that the outcomes were we to treat the objects as distinct rather than identical as being equally likely to occur.

Comment: @lulu Ah!, I got it. So, in your example, let the objects be $O_1, O_2, O_3$. Here, the pattern $(1,1,1)$ consists of $(O_1, O_2, O_3), (O_1,O_3, O_2), (O_2, O_1, O_3) $ etc which we were missing out, right? Here, $( \ ,\ ,\ )$ represents the $3$ slots, all coordinates having capacity three.

Comment: @JMoravitz many of the outcomes in my solutions are grouped into one which creates a non-uniform probability distribution. I got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Saikat  Yes, that's it exactly.  As others have remarked, the point is that there are a great many ways to get uniform or near-uniform distributions of the objects, but only a small number of ways to highly clustered arrangements.